# .htaccess redirect 301 www.domain.com/dir_one to www.domain.com/dir_one/dir_two

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How can I make a redirect from `.htaccess`:

```
redirect 301 www.domain.com/dir_one to www.domain.com/dir_one/dir_two
```

I have already tried

```
Redirect 301 /dir_one/  http://www.domain.com/dir_one/dir_two
```

but then I end up in a endless loop like www.domain.com/dir_one/dir_twodir_two ... and so on
and have this in the `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Thanks for helping!
Simone

Comment: `RewriteRule dir_one/?$  http://www.domain.com/dir_one/dir_two [R=301,L]`

Comment: No, don't work.  Same as before. endless loop

Comment: Solved it on my own. Thanks